# Sobre R y su licencia GPL-3

Tags: r, licencias

Siendo `R` distribuido bajo licencia `GPL-3`,

¿No deberían todos los paquetes y otros *Scripts* ser distribuidos bajo la misma licencia ? Pregunto, porque he visto que muchos paquetes se distribuyen bajo otras licencias como `MIT.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es necesario, GPLP permite lo que se conoce como licencias "compatibles", incluso bajo ciertas circunstancias se puede distribuir software propietario. Para más información de cuales son las licencias compatibles te sugiero ver [este](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#GPLCompatibleLicenses) enlace.

Comment: Gracias @Patricio por la respuesta es clara y concisa.

Comment: Clara, concisa pero ligeramente confusa (ver mi respuesta más abajo).

Answer (score 0):

Si tú haces un producto derivado *del código fuente de la implementación de R* (por ejemplo: una versión nueva de R que haga cosas distintas, un producto que modifique el lenguaje R), ese producto *tiene* que ser distribuido con la licencia GPL3. No obstante, el código R puede estar distribuido bajo cualquier licencia independientemente de la licencia de R. Son dos aspectos independientes.

Otor ejemplo: MATLAB es un producto privativo, pero yo puedo publicar código MATLAB con cualquier licencia.

Comment: Gracias @astrojuanlu por agregar luz al asunto.